# Print the Pascal triangle when input the height of this triangle in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial(int a){
    int b;
    if (a==0)
        return 1;
    else
        for (b=1;b<=a;b++)
        a=a*b;
}   //factorial of a
int pascal(int i, int j){

        return (factorial(i))/((factorial(j))*factorial(i-j));

}   
int main()
{
    int k,n,m,q;
    printf("Input m: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    for(k=0;k<m;k++){
        for(n=0;n<=k;n++)
            printf("%d ", pascal(k, n));

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I make a program that print the Pascal triangle but it make the right answer if height<=3, when I input m=6; it will print:

```
1
1 1
1 3 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Can you help me find the bugs in my code?

Comment: You need `return a;`in the factorial function.

Comment: Your `factorial` function is just plain wrong. You are modifying `a` in the `for` loop and then comparing `b` to the modified value. You'll get all sorts of integer overflows.

Comment: So How should i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

that's because you have written the wrong logic in the function factorial().

```
for (b=1;b<=a;b++)
    a=a*b;//also , you have to return the value of a here!
```

here, suppose a = 3, then, in 1st iteration, a = 3*1 equals 3, in 2nd iteration, a=3*2 equals 6; since 6>3 ,loop terminates and you got the right answer!!
but if a = 4, then, in 1st iteration, a = 4*1 equals 4, in 2nd iteration, a=4*2 equals 8 which is greater than 4, therefore loop does not executes further and you got the wrong answer!
the correct logic would be, to declare another int variable and initialize it to 1 to store the product of 'a' and the variable in it itself i.e,

```
 int fac=1;
    for(b=1;b<=a;b++){
        fac = fac*b;
    }
    return fac;
```

so, the full code will be,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial(int a){
int b=0;
if (a==0)
    return 1;
else{

   /* for(b=1;b<=a;b++){         
        fac = b*(factorial(b-1));// another way to find factorial using recursion
return fac;    
}*/
    int fac=1;
    for(b=1;b<=a;b++){
        fac = fac*b;
    }
    return fac;
  }

}   //factorial of a

int pascal(int i, int j){

    return factorial(i) / (factorial(j) *factorial(i-j));
 }
int main()
{
  int k,n,m,q;

   printf("Input m: ");
   scanf("%d", &m);

   for(k=0;k<m;k++){
    for(n=0;n<=k;n++)
        printf("%d ", pascal(k, n));

    printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;  // a good habit to add return 0, to let the compiler know that
             // the code is executed completely    
}
```